# Impossible to get out of "gsReference.getFile(Objects.requireNonNull(localFile)).addOnSuccessListener"

Tags: java, android, firebase, opencsv, csvreader

I am trying to get a value from the first line of a csv file ( header excluded) store in Firebase Storage

Here is the code :

```
private String readFromCsv() {

    StorageReference refCompteActifs = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("my_file").child("my_file.csv");
    StorageReference gsReference = refCompteActifs.getStorage().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://test-8095e.appspot.com/my_file/my_filer.csv");
    File localFile = null;
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("my_file", ".csv");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File finalLocalFile = localFile;
    final String[] result = {null};
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    gsReference.getFile(Objects.requireNonNull(localFile)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            try {
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("./data/user/0/com.example.test/cache/" + finalLocalFile.getName()), ',', '\'', 1);
                String[] nextLine = null;

                while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(nextLine[4] + "\n");
                    rows.add(nextLine[4]);
                    

                }

              
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
                result[0] = rows.get(i);
            }

        }

    }
    System.out.println(result[0] + "\n");
    return result[0];
}
```

The console never write "System.out.println(result[0] + "\n");" result[0] is affected inside the onlistener but I can't access it outside of it.

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. The `getFile` API is an asynchronous operation, which means that it executes in the background while the rest of your code continues to run. Then when the operation is complete, your `onSuccess` is called with the result.

This is easiest to see if you add some logging:

```
Log.i("File", "1. Starting to load file");
gsReference.getFile(Objects.requireNonNull(localFile)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Log.i("File", "2. Loaded file");
    }

}
Log.i("File", "3. Started to load file");
```

If you run this code it outputs:

> 1. Starting to load file
> 2. Started to load file
> 3. Loaded file

This is probably not what you expected, but it is working by design - and it does completely explain why your `System.out.println(result[0] + "\n");` doesn't show the file contents: the file hasn't been loaded yet.

This is an incredibly common problem, as most I/O and network APIs are asynchronous these days. The solution is always the same: any code that needs the data that is asynchronously loaded has to be inside the `onSuccess` handler, be called from there, or otherwise synchronized.

This means for example that you can't **return** the value from the file, as the `return` runs before the load has completed, and you'll instead want to pass a callback to your `readFromCsv` function, very similar to the `OnSuccessListener`.

For more on this, I recommend reading:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)
- more [questions on losing the asynchronous value outside of a callback](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%5Bandroid%5D+asynchronous+loses+value+outside)